# While testing login API in Postman, I am getting required response but console shows exception. (SpringBoot Parent starter v- 2.7.12)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

```
@Override
   public ResponseEntity<String> signUp(RequestPayload requestPayload) {

       log.info("Inside signup service {}", requestPayload);
       try {
           if (validateSignUpMap(requestPayload)) {
               User user = this.userRepository.findByEmailId(requestPayload.getRequestMap().get("email"));
               log.info("user :- {}", user);
               if (Objects.isNull(user)) {
                   this.userRepository.save((getUserFromMap(requestPayload)));
                   log.info("user saved in database {}", user);
                   return CafeUtils.getResponseEntity("Successfully Registered", HttpStatus.OK);
               } else {
                   log.info("user not saved in database because email id already exists {}", user.getEmail());
                   return CafeUtils.getResponseEntity("Email already exists", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
               }
           } else {
               log.info("user not saved in database because invalid details {}", requestPayload);
               return CafeUtils.getResponseEntity(CafeConstants.INVALID_DATA, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
           }
       } catch (Exception ex){
           ex.printStackTrace();
       }
       log.info("could not execute signup logic", requestPayload);
       return CafeUtils.getResponseEntity(CafeConstants.SOMETHING_WENT_WRONG, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
   }
```

This is the my service method for signup API. I have printed the logs also to debug the problem. Console output is as follows:

```
2023-06-02 11:37:34.317  INFO 22404 --- [nio-9090-exec-2] 
com.cafe.serviceImpl.UserServiceImpl : Inside signup service RequestPayload(requestMap={name=zxsd, contactNumber=123456789, email=test@gmail.com, password=1234})


Hibernate:   
    select  
        user0_.id as id1_0_,  
        user0_.contact_number as contact_2_0_,  
        user0_.email as email3_0_,  
        user0_.name as name4_0_,  
        user0_.password as password5_0_,  
        user0_.role as role6_0_,  
        user0_.status as status7_0_   
    from  
        user user0_   
    where  
        user0_.email=?  
  


2023-06-02 11:37:34.369  INFO 22404 --- [nio-9090-exec-2] com.cafe.serviceImpl.UserServiceImpl : user :- User(id=5, name=zxsd, contactNumber=9175785585, email=test@gmail.com, password=1234, status=false, role=user)

2023-06-02 11:37:34.385  INFO 22404 --- [nio-9090-exec-2] com.cafe.serviceImpl.UserServiceImpl     : user not saved in database because email id already exists test@gmail.com

2023-06-02 11:37:34.428  WARN 22404 --- [nio-9090-exec-2] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Failure while trying to resolve exception [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException]

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call sendError() after the response has been committed
```

My request in postman is like:

```
{  
   "requestMap" : {  
    "name" : "zxsd",  
    "contactNumber" : "123456789",  
    "email" : "test@gmail.com",  
    "password" : "1234"  
    }  
}
```

And getting the desired output as well also.

Postman console:

```
{  
    "message": "Email already exists"  
}
```